# Naming various iterations within a loop

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have produced a loop which step-wise applies a mask with increasing threshold to an image.  Using the Map.addLayer() feature, I wish to view all outputs however I do not seem to be able to name them different things within the loop:

```js
for (var i = 0.85; i < 0.96; i += 0.01){

    //sets the threshold
    var threshold = ee.Number(i);

    //two input images from the minumum and the error
    var min = ee.Image(image4);
    var error = ee.Image(image3);

    //applies the threshold to the minimum image
    var percent_mask = 
    min.select('b1').lte(error.select('b1').multiply(threshold));
    var masked_percent = min.updateMask(percent_mask);


    Map.addLayer(masked_percent, {}, 'name');

}
```

I wish to replace `'name'` with something unique, preferably something to do with the threshold applied for each output.

Full code with assets can be found here:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/6e4c1c3c4691e29f7149176447076197

Answer (score 1):

Since you are executing a client side loop you could use the threshold as a name for the added bands:

```js
Map.addLayer(masked_percent, {}, 'threshold_'+i.toString());
```

Please also refer to the [client vs. server](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server) documentation if you plan to do the thresholding over larger amounts of data. As Tyler pointed out `Map.addLayer` is a client side operation anyway. You might run into issues, such as your browser crashing, if you try to visualize too many thresholded masks.

Comment: Given that Map.addLayer() is a client side operation, you don't have the options for moving it server-side.

Comment: I was referring to the processing of larger thresholding intervals with a mapped `addBands`. Thanks for the remark, I'll edit the post.